# How to compare a defaultdict of defaultdict of list of strings with a particular list of strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to compare a defaultdict of defaultdict, that has a list of strings for each couple of keys, with my_list, that has been already read from a txt file. My dictionary is defined as d[website][plugin]. What I want to do is check, for each website and plugin in the dictionary, if each element (present inside the list of the dictionary) is present in my_list or not. If yes, I want to save that element in another defaultdict of default dict of list, otherwise I skip the element without save it.

I wrote this code to read from file and to save the elements inside the dictionary:

```
import glob
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pls
d = defaultdict( lambda : defaultdict ( lambda : [] ) )

with open("ghosteryList.txt", "r") as f:
lista_completa_trackers = []
for line in f:
    lista_completa_trackers.append(line)

for file in glob.glob('*/*_finito.txt'):
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        if row == "\n":
            continue  
        splitted=row.split()
        site=file.split("/")[-1].split("_")[0]
        plugin=file.split("/")[-2].split("_")[1]
        d[site][plugin].append(splitted[0])

for sito in d:
    for plugin in d[sito]:
        for elem in d[sito][plugin]:
            #print(elem)
            if(elem in el for el in lista_completa_trackers):
                print(sito, plugin, elem)
```

but I don't know how consider each element inside the dictionary list. Is it correct?
How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide an explanation by referencing sample data and code instead please. It will be easier to visualize and help understand your problem better.

Comment: Have you tried this? What happened?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: It is not correct because the "filtering" in the last part of the code doesn't work. I tried it and it does filter nothing.

Comment: Create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means remove all irrelevant code (glob, file parsing etc). Just create a hard-coded dict of whatever with some values and the function which should compare it with something (show that something hard-coded as well). Then write which result you expect and which you get.

Comment: OT, consider the possibility that *"a defaultdict of defaultdict of list of strings"* is not the best data structure for whatever you are doing. When it sounds too complex, it usually is too complex. Or, as [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) says: *"If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea."*